# Why can't Yoda speak in proper English grammar?

Tags: star-wars

Yoda, being a Jedi grand master, should have better communication skills given that he is supreme leader among the Jedis. Why can't he learn to speak English properly?

Comment: When you a Jedi grand master are, your own grammar invent can you.

Comment: Deeply disappointed am I, phrased it was not: 'Why use proper grammar did Master Yoda not?'

Comment: “Yoda, being a Jedi grand master, should have better communication skills” — do you feel like anyone in the movies had difficulty understanding him?

Comment: When 900 years old you are, give a crap about grammar, you will not.

Comment: I bet Yoda didn't mix up "Jedis" with its correct plural, "Jedi".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

His way of speaking reflects his personality (he always puts actions last).

Comment: Maybe Yoda is a German. This is German grammar.

Comment: @user486818 almost, but not 100%. This would sound weird in German as well. Plus in the German translation, Yoda sounds weird as well.

Comment: Not only the action, but also the subject, e.g. sentences ending with "you are" "you must", etc. So Marks example seems wrong to me, I think it should be "When a Jedi grand master you are, your own grammar invent you can"

Answer (score 9):

The same reason many people here on earth can't. Because he's not English.

Comment: I always considered it to be the equivalent of an alien 'accent'.  Some people learn to speak the language of the people they're living around without an accent, some don't.  Two of my grandparents were 'off the boat' from  Poland in the 1920s, as children; one retained a lifelong thick Polish accent and the other didn't.

Comment: I feel like this ignores the fact that the English are a minority of the English speakers in the world.